# ThreeJS r75 bindTexture: textures can not be used with multiple targets

Tags: three.js, webgl, warnings

My code is triggering this warning in ThreeJS r75:

bindTexture: textures can not be used with multiple targets.

I have a basic understanding of the error.

If I remove the 2 cubeCameras I create for reflection purposes, the warning isn't triggered.

My questions are:  Is the warning a bug?  Should the cubeCameras be triggering this warning?  Am I creating the cubeCameras in way that isn't correct for r75?

This is how I create them:

```
gongRef = new THREE.CubeCamera(1, 32000, 1024);
```

This is how I add them to the scene:

```
scene.add(gongRef );
```

This is how I apply them:

```
gongMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color:"rgb(240,240,240)",
        specular:"rgb(240,240,240)",
        shininess:200,
        emissive:"rgb(140,140,140)",
        visible:true,
        wireframe:false,
        envMap:gongRef.renderTarget,
        reflectivity: 0.8,
        emissiveIntensity: 1.0
        });
```

This is how I update them:

```
gongRef.position.copy(theGong.position);
theGong.visible = false;                
gongRef.updateCubeMap( renderer, scene );
theGong.visible = true;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On GitHub, Mr. Doob replied, "I think this has already been fixed in the dev branch.."

So, I guess it's a little bug in the warnings for bindTexture.